# What is the difference between a filepath prepended with a `/` and one where it is omitted?

Tags: php, path, namespaces, filepath

What is the difference between:

`/../../../my_dir/my_file.php`
And
`../../../my_dir/my_file.php`

I was working with a PHP include (couldn't include regularly, i suspect it is because i used namespaces in the file i was including from), the latter didn't work, i randomly added the `/` before the filepath and now everything is working fine. I am utterly confused since after reading about the functionality of that forward slash, it appears that my code shouldn't work since `/` refers to the root directory, therefore `/../../../` is three levels up the root directory ? What the hell would that even mean ? I really have no idea why my code is working and that file is being included.

So, if `/` is the root directory, and i am going up three levels up the root, then why does everything work fine ? shouldn't it throw some error ?

Additionally, can the root directory change ? As i understand it, in Windows, my root directory right now is the `C:` drive, could you change your root from `C:` to say, a directory in your project ?

Here is a gist if you are interested in taking a look at the file where all this is going on: https://gist.github.com/doubleOrt/09a2b0b97f632143f89e07f21bb974ad

Comment: the leading slash say GO TO THE ROOT FOLDER. Without it applied the pathing instructions from where you are

Comment: Yes, but see the description of my question. This is the part i don't get, if i am going to the root folder (in Windows, my `C:` drive, right ?), and then i am going up a few levels, then why does my code work ? Where do i end up when i go to the parents of the root folder ? What is the parent of the root folder ?

Comment: Relative and absolute paths.

Comment: Of course, you can not go up from root folder.

Comment: I am pretty sure, mistakes like that are just ignored

Comment: @IvanBolnikh So, is `C:` my root folder in all cases (in Windows), are there any exceptions to this rule ? could the root folder change to, say a directory in my project ? Could this be why my code is working ?

Comment: @RiggsFolly which sorts ?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Me going up the root folder ? Then why does my include work fine ? I am including a file that connects to the database and i am able to use it regularly.

Comment: I try on windows - and found that PHP silently ignore switch to upper folder when you are on root.

Comment: @IvanBolnikh Weird, then why is my include working fine ? I assume it is because some library i am including via Composer is changing my root.

Comment: @Taurus - root doesn't change..... your root on C: is always C:\

Comment: @IvanBolnikh See my code here, if you are interested: https://gist.github.com/doubleOrt/09a2b0b97f632143f89e07f21bb974ad

Answer (score 0):

> /../../../my_dir/my_file.php

This will change directory based on the root.

> ./../../../my_dir/my_file.php

This will change the directory, relative to where it's executed

> ../../../../my_dir/my_file.php

This just goes up up up and up to my_dir/my_file.php

> As i understand it, in Windows, my root directory right now is the C: drive, could you change your root from C: to say, a directory in your project ?

Not sure, but you wouldn't want this, as it would be different from your live environment. Root should always be the root.

Comment: Link to my code: https://gist.github.com/doubleOrt/09a2b0b97f632143f89e07f21bb974ad

Comment: @Taurus ok... you asked for the difference, not sure what else you want?

Comment: Why is my code working if i am actually going up the root directory ? See the description of my question, i've added a few more things.

Comment: @Taurus Just accept it does. Some things just aren't worth the effort of figuring out. Stick with either `./dir/name` or `../dir/name` or `/dir/name` and you'll be fine. There are some weird things in PHP.